# What books are in a modern Peshitta?

Tags: bible, bible-translation, canon, resource-request, books

I'm looking to buy a copy of the Peshitta so that I can learn Syriac, but I understand that it has gradually changed throughout history. The antilogemmon were excluded for the first 500 years or so for example.

I'm wondering what it's current form is? What books are included in the Peshitta Old Testament and Peshitta New Testament today? I don't want to end up buying some protestantised edition which only included 66 books while the actual peshitta has 86 (for example).

Comment: I'm sure there is a lot of "helpful" information on the web, but the Syriac Patriarchate of Antioch has some contacts related to their manuscript collection posted on [this page](http://syriacpatriarchate.org/st-aphrem-theological-seminary/patriarchal-collection-manuscripts/).  It might be interesting to reach out to them and ask for guidance.  They might even have some resources to help your studies.

Comment: According to wiki, the UBS Peshitta has the protocanonical 66 + 11 deutero-and-or-apocraphal books. Historically, Peshitta did not include some NT books (2-3 Jn, 2 Pe, etc.) but these were added in the sixth century. peshita.org has 4 gospels and Acts interlinear, and (apparently) all the books if you look for them, but not all in Aramaic yet. Presumably in progress, but interesting.